# Zend_Controller_Request remove GET query

Tags: php, zend-framework

How could I remove the get query from the URI, so I can use this method:

```
$request->getRequestUri()
```

And get the URI without the GET query part?

I.e. this:

```
/module/controller/action/par/val?par2=aaa
```

I would get:

```
/module/controller/action/par/val
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about a ZF-specific way, but I think this would work:

```
<?PHP
$path = parse_url($request->getRequestUri(),PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Comment: I just used current(explode('?', $request->getRequestUri())) after all and it worked great. But thanks!